# How to execute console or GUI input as if it was actual Java code?

Tags: java, compilation, io, console, runtime

I want to be able to input java commands/code to execute during run-time (during the execution of a "persistent" program) in the same way, or as close as possible, to the same code would be executed if it was present on the source-code for the program (programmed as part of the software), using a GUI element, like jTextArea.

---

The following StackOverflow questions seem to be related, but, along with they'r answers, don't seem to be what i'm looking for.

[How To Get Input From Console Class In Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/how-to-get-input-from-console-class-in-java)

[Using GUI for console input and outputin java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128309/using-gui-for-console-input-and-outputin-java)

I **don't** want to "be able to trigger actions from specific console inputs, and print the feedback into the console", as seems to be the case of console applications described in those question and answers.

What i want is to "be able to execute actual java code, that i cannot predict nor control, from console (or GUI) input".

*NOTE: The "i cannot predict nor control" here refers to the "developer"...But of course i can predict and "control" it if i'm the one inputting the code, as the "user" would do.*

---

Since java uses a virtual-machine environment, i think it might be possible for it to execute "run-time inputted code"...But i'm not sure such thing is even possible.

For example, i'd like the run-time input of `for(int i=0; i<3; i++){System.out.println(i);}` in the "GUI console" (jTextArea, for example) to, upon pressing the enter key or clicking a "Send" button, be ("compiled and "?) executed, and give the same output as if it was part of the original source-code, thus:

```
0
1
2
```

So i'd like to know the following:

- Is it possible?
- If yes, how can i do it? (OR, if no, what is the closest alternative?)

Comment: This is not easy in any compiled language, the JVM is no bonus here. It's possible, but non-trivial at best.

Comment: i think this would be called reflection

Comment: This is completely trivial; there's a Java compilation API, just put the code into a main function and a temporary class. IMO bean shell, JRuby, groovy, etc via the scripting API would be easier. Though. Either way, not difficult. @Randy, not reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).  It can compile code from a `String`.

For an E.G. see the [STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/) & especially the [source code](http://pscode.org/stbc/#develop).  It provides a GUI and can compile the code in the text area on button click.

[image: STBC GUI]

But note the:

### [System Requirements](http://pscode.org/stbc/#minimumrequirement)

STBC will run on any computer with a version 1.6+ Java <strike>Plug-In</strike>* JDK (AKA SDK).

(*) The API that STBC uses is merely a public interface to the compiler in the `tools.jar` that is distributed only with JDKs (though the 'public JRE' of the JDK also seems to acquire a `tools.jar`). This leads to some unusual requirements in running either the native jar, or the web start app.

Comment: Tough Josh was first to answer, your's is simpler to follow, even more resourceful (tough access to a source-code example was not as direct), and better formatted. +1 and chosen.

Comment: I was also was compelled to up-vote the answer of @Josh, as the first answer that was suggesting what I was about to.  In fact, I considered just adding a comment, but thought I would do this question better justice as an answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html), as this question's answer states:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/935316/420001

Also, what you're wanting to do is `evaluate` a `String` of `code`:

It's not really recommended though.

Comment: Nice! It's exactly what i was looking for! And now i know how to refer to it properly too! ("to evaluate and convert a String of code into compilable code, compile, and execute it" - Based on yours and the indicated source's texts) Many thanks Josh! A +1 is well deserved, not only for the first response, but for it being very helpful and resourceful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html)

"In short, BeanShell is dynamically interpreted Java, plus a scripting language and flexible environment all rolled into one clean package. "

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer but for future Googlers:

I would recommend ***JavaREPL*** whose source is available here: 
https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl

What *AlmightyR* is asking for is called Read-Eval-Print-Loop (REPL) for the Java language which is what JavaREPL provides.

JavaREPL has an online demo available here: http://www.javarepl.com/console.html

JavaREPL also has an Intellij plugin and a CLI version which are both linked to in the Github repository.

It looks sort of abandoned currently but perhaps it just doesn't need to be maintained?